# How to escape ? in Ansible task?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to include a JSON query in the actual task?  All of the examples show using an additional var for the query.

Taking the example from [Ansible Filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

```
- name: "Display all ports from cluster1"
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ domain_definition | json_query(server_name_cluster1_query) }}"
  vars:
    server_name_cluster1_query: "domain.server[?cluster=='cluster1'].port"
```

Converted to:

```
- name: "Display all ports from cluster1"
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ domain_definition | json_query(domain.server[?cluster=='cluster1'].port) }}"
```

as is it returns:

> FAILED! => {"reason": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  found unknown escape character '?'

I have tried to add an escape backslash before the question mark, but it still fails with:

> "template error while templating string: unexpected char '?'

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use back-ticks *`* . For example

```
- name: "Display all ports from cluster1"
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ domain_definition | json_query('domain.server[?cluster==`cluster1`].port') }}"
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears you can escape double quote the query and it will work!

```
- name: "Display all ports from cluster1"
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ domain_definition | json_query(\"domain.server[?cluster=='cluster1'].port\") }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To step a little bit aside from escape hell, I like to take advantage of [yaml scalar blocks](https://yaml-multiline.info/)

```
- name: "Display all ports from cluster1"
  vars:
    my_query: >-
      domain.server[?cluster=='cluster1'].port
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ domain_definition | json_query(my_query) }}"
```

You don't have to escape anything this way (works for quotes and backslash as well, nice for regexps)